# What if reputation points have an expiration date?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Here's a feature request I would like to discuss about on MSO. You all know that being up-to-date in the field of programming is essential.

Therefore, I would like to suggest a feature: *would it be possible for reputation points to vanish out during time?*

Here's my thought: a 300k-rep user might have gained all his reputation points thanks to an old version of a programming language and not be up-to-date to all new technologies. In consequence, his reputation level might not reflect his true skills at the moment.

I don't have the algorithm on top of my mind yet but we could imagine something like:

- accepted answers points last 2 years
- upvotes points last 1 year

Therefore, old contributions that are no longer active and don't receive upvotes anymore would have less impact on the reputation level than other active topics.

All of this in order to have the reputation level to **truly reflect the *current* skills and not outdated ones.**

Comment: Old versions of software, languages and technology are still in use, in some cases there is still code use that is several decades old so old knowledge can still be very valuable.

Comment: I would expect this to simply change the values, not much more. high rep users will still be high rep, because their old questions are still receiving upvotes.

Comment: @KevinB: Sure, if questions are still useful now. But what about old ones that are outdated?

Comment: How do you determine if a question is outdated and no one can gain useful information from it?

Comment: @JoeW: By upvotes. If old knowledge is still valuable, it will still receive upvotes, therefore maintaining the reputation level. But old outdated questions would have therefore less impact on the reputation.

Comment: knowledge being valuable does not mean the question/answer will get a lot of traffic or votes. Or just because it is useful to a small group doesn't mean it isn't valuable.

Comment: See also [Legacy code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_code) and [tag:cobol].

Comment: My primary issue with this is if we're going to expire votes, we're also expiring downvotes. I have less of an issue with the upvotes expiring, but, only expiring one without the other seems wrong too.

Comment: @KevinB Good point, some people might gain rep from expired votes.

Comment: Expiring downvotes making gain points is something I haven't thought about. Very good point.

Comment: Has this been tested against actual, old contributions from page 1 users? Take a peek; are most of them actually less useful now than they were at the time of writing? My strong suspicion is that most super-high-rep users' answers will often be put in a way that transcends a specific version.

Comment: I chuckled when I saw how many downvotes this had. Of course the people in charge here who have all the reputation accumulated from eons ago are never going to agree to give that up. It's like asking Congress to pass term limits for themselves. What really grinds my gears is when you have people with 10k or even 100k reputation based on questions asked 10 years ago making useless comments and knee-jerk votes to close stuff that they have no business opining on. But of course it will never change.

Comment: @PeterMoore my issue with this feature request is more... it's a complex solution to a problem that hasn't yet been proven to be a problem. If you want to believe it's because i want to keep hold of my 92k rep, consider how much of my own rep I've deleted by casting downvotes on wrong/low quality answers to date. somewhere in the range of... 13k-17k? surely if it's the rep i cared about i wouldn't be throwing it away.

Comment: @kevinb obviously I'm not going to single anyone out, nor did I mean to imply anyone who was opposed to this idea was opposed for the wrong reasons. But in the aggregate, peoples' actions virtually always align with their incentives. The people who have the most power to change the system have the least incentive to do so.

Comment: The majority of these... "power users" make more rep a year without participating than the avg user has total. Heck I made more than 1.5k this year alone without a single answer. Expiring reputation will not change anything. The people who have a lot of rep have a lot of rep because they get rep daily from their positive contributions. Should upvotes just not reward rep?

Comment: @kevinb no, you are the opposite of the problem. If you're making rep points today in your sleep based on old answers it's because your old answers are still useful. Which is great! You deserve the points. It's the STALE answers/points that are the issue. My suggestion would be very simple: everyone atrophies points over time. 10% per year perhaps. Every day, everyone's reputation drops by 10%/365. For a 10,000 rep user that amounts to 2.74 points per day. Are you getting at least one upvote every 4 days? Then your reputation stays stable. It's about relevance. Freshness.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are missing the point. Reputation was never about skill (though it takes some to get it). It *is* a measure of your contributions to the community, and those last forever.

In summary, I don't see any value in this feature.

Comment: Nice summary, the rest of your post was too long to read. :)

Comment: @TZHX And here I thought the main body was too short :D

Comment: @TZHX yeah, the vast wall of text that makes up the first paragraph was too much for me too. Glad there was a summary!