# How to interact on Stack Overflow regardless of our reputation points level?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, reputation-bias

Following [this comment on one of my last meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299764/what-to-do-so-reputation-level-doesnt-influence-our-interactions-on-stack-overf#comment223312_299764), I decide to do this separate post.

My question is: *how not to be impacted by our reputation points level when interacting with others on Stack Overflow?*

I have to face it, this gain of reputation points has clearly made me have more confidence in myself. Not only because I'm part of the [happy-few who have significant amount of points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297074/2788131) but also because I know my skills have improved. Therefore, I'm much more comfortable in helping others as I used to do when I was a 1-rep user.

However, reputation points level can sometimes be misleading. [It is not an exact reflection of the skill level](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299945/2788131) and thinking so is part of the [reputation-bias](/questions/tagged/reputation-bias). [Someone with low-rep level can be high-skilled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162584/timbl) and vice-versa.

Also, having too much confidence can be counter-productive: if I tend not to listen carefully when a lower-rep user is stating something, I might miss something that I didn't know. I know, however, that I do pay attention to what higher-rep users say to me, even though they may be less skilled than me in a specific domain. Besides, [I'm not the only one who thinks that this reputation system has an impact on interactions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late).

I guess there must be a threshold when this whole reputation system doesn't have an impact anymore. Maybe when the gamification is over by having [unlocked all the privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

In short, this reputation system is quite useful to measure contributions to the community but what actions does someone need to take in order not to be impacted by its reputation points level when interacting with others on Stack Overflow?

Comment: There’s always the possibility of installing a stylesheet in your browser to the effect of `.post-signature { display: none; }`…

Comment: `what do I need to do so my rep level doesn't impact my interactions with others?` Isn't that something you should be asking yourself?... Not sure it is something anyone here can answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃: For sure it is a personal question but I'm looking here for others contributors who would share my point of view and would have tips on that.

Answer (score 10):

## Treat every encounter as a new instance.

### Assume nothing and go from there.

There are some people who have or had 1 reputation which I felt were pretty brilliant, simply from the question or answer that they had posted.  There are some people who have substantially more - on the order of 10K or more - who I felt really shouldn't be let near a computer based on their interactions.

It also helps when you don't presume that you or anyone else is correct simply because one's reputation is high.  Keeping humble, being clear, and being accurate helps establish correctness and, in turn, establishes reputation, but don't let it go to one's head.  In spite of the absolute rareness of it, even Jon Skeet has had a few answers get away from him before.

Ultimately though, as you unlock more and more privileges, your reputation level *does* impact how you interact with community members.

- A downvote is the earliest example of this; you spend 1 reputation to send -2 reputation to someone else for any old reason.
- You start to be able to see vote counts at 1K, and you may be tempted to draw an opinion of how to vote from seeing that instead of the question.
- When you can see deleted content at 10K+, you draw an opinion of the person that posted what is now deleted.
- Past 35K, you have unlocked virtually everything which includes the maximum amount of deletions, so you could be slanted towards deleting all of the bad things and draw biases towards that which you are voting to delete.

The main advice is as stated:  treat every interaction as a new interaction, even if it's with the same person.  Only in certain situations should you start drawing parallels or conclusions on someone; that is, if they're starting to show serious signs of being a jerk around here.

Comment: Actually, an upvote is the first which counts, the downvote coming later. That doen's invalidate anything though.

Comment: _Past 35K, you have unlocked virtually everything_ I thought that [happened at 20K](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), have I missed something?

Comment: @jpw:  [At 35K you get the maximum 30 deletions per day.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: @Makoto Ah, ok. I had no idea. Thanks.