# Over time, on Stack Overflow, it is harder to earn a great deal of reputation. What can we do?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am quite new to this great site and am definitely not a programming genius. But what I want to bring up as a problem is that IMHO it is much harder to earn lots of reputation points than it was in the first years of this site's existence.

Why do I think so? If you check some very popular questions and answers you will see they touch some basic and very useful topic from popular technology, like *[How do I revert an SVN commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330011/how-to-revert-an-svn-commit)*, that many programmers deal with every day. These topics are fundamental for each technology. I am almost sure that ~98% of possible topics like that were already asked and answered for current, past and contemporary technologies. There are exceptions of course.

New technologies emerge every day, and these kinds of topics can be started, but a number of them will be much lower as when Stack Overflow started there where already many technologies on market, and these members of Stack Overflow who were here from the beginning had more chance to earn 1000s of points.

I have no idea what could be the solution and I am not even sure this is REAL problem for any person, but these are my thoughts that you may share or deny.

Comment: They are fake internet points...in the end...they don't matter. Concentrate on providing good Questions &/or Answers and the points will come.

Comment: Focusing on a homerun like that will never get you anywhere, it is complete accident and totally out of your control.  Building reputation is like tending a Japanese bonsai garden, it takes years of careful pruning and constant watering.  Not that many SO users have the patience or dedication, it can only work when you enjoy contributing for your own benefit and avoid focusing on the rep game.

Comment: Is this the monthly _"Why is it so hard for noobs to earn rep"_ question? I think there's quite a few duplicates of this one.

Comment: If you are posting because of the rep it gives you rather then because you enjoy helping people and growing by answering questions then you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Here are [1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5927417/thomas-lotze), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5879270/jilson-thomas), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5932444/sergey-vidusov) people who if they keep up their current rate of reputation gain will be at 10k after ~150 days... people are still able to get rep fast. If you copied [MrGomez](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127021/179419) you could do it in ~3 weeks.

Comment: I started 'late' (mid 2012). I had no problems gaining a top 15 spot from wherever I started. Not that I focused on that; I focused on creating answers that helped.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Reddit's karma system is fake internet points. It means literally nothing. SO's reputation system actually does have some meaning - it grants users additional permissions to moderate the site. For users who want to become more involved in the community but aren't quite as knowledgeable, reputation certainly has some concrete value. If reputation was completely meaningless, we wouldn't be so uptight about which questions/answers we up/downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so basically the trick is find a tag where there are a lot of questions to ask, and get to work. Python has treated you well :) I can venture a guess that [tag:scala] right now is a tag to love for reputation as a language soaring in popularity.

Comment: It is noticeable how often people with a very high reputation _disqualify_ questions like this **out of hand**. I also feel it's true that earning points has become harder over the years. It's almost self-evident. However, I could be wrong, I have no objective data. I can see my own reputation in some detail, but not of other users. People who do have access to the data of many users are probably not interested in sharing what they know?

Answer (score 19):

It probably is more difficult for new users to gain a lot of points in popular tags like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) than it used to be. Average question quality in those tags was much higher back in those days, so it was a lot easier to find questions to answer without wading through all the low-quality or duplicate questions that we see today.

If I were you, I'd focus on less popular tags like [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d). (Just an example. I see you're already active in that tag.) There might be fewer questions to answer, but that means you have more time to focus on giving really good answers to the higher-quality questions in that tag. Also, it takes a lot less reputation to get on the [leader board](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/topusers) for that tag, which is really the kind of thing you want to show off to a potential employer.

Comment: Typo and duplicate questions and their answers get upvoted every day. I'd say C# is one of the easiest tags to earn reputation, frankly. Copy-paste the title into Google, paste the first result you find and voilà. Upvotes do not indicate answer quality.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you get tens (or hundreds) of upvotes for a single answer on those kinds of questions, or do you have to answer 10 of them a day to hit the reputation cap? That sounds like a lot of pointless work to me. Also, I would hope that over time those questions are getting closed and deleted.

Comment: I don't know, I don't answer them. I do see answers to such questions get 1-5 upvotes for their effort, regardless of question quality. It's way easier to answer ten such questions a day than to find a properly interesting question and doing the research required to answer it properly. Just take a look at `c#` + `asp.net-mvc`, or if you're really feeling like spending your daily votes, `c#` + `regex`.

Answer (score 13):

It is no harder to earn reputation than it once was. If anything, it is easier simply because there are a lot more users who will see and are eligible to vote on your contributions.

The reputation earned for [those old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330011/how-to-revert-an-svn-commit) was earned *over time*, not all at once when the question was first posted. (That couldn't possibly have been the case, considering there is a 200-point reputation cap each day.) The old-timers have lots of reputation because they've been around a long time, contributing useful content. There is no real problem to be solved here. If you hang around long enough and contribute enough useful content, you too will gain upvotes and be awarded reputation.

The last real [privilege milestone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) is 10k, at which point you have [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). There are a few token privileges after that, but they are of significantly decreased interest. Having 100k+ reputation doesn't really get you anything but bragging rights. You can't cash them in for a coffee.

Comment: In fact it has even caused some discomfort when people magically started to see deleted answers they did not want to see :)

Comment: Per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a you do get some bits of swag at 100k / 200k points. Jon Skeet got a [unicorn painting](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/), being the first person to hit 200k. I believe the current reward is a T-shirt at 100k, though I'm sure it's up to whoever cares.

Comment: @cube It has happened before, but it is not guaranteed. If I remember correctly, I got a t-shirt before reaching 100k, but it wasn't as cool as Martijin's. But it's true that you are subject to get cool swag when you reach a high rep count. That in itself is hardly enough motivation. You can buy your own t-shirt for a lot less than the time Jon and Martijin have invested in this site. :-)

Comment: _"hardly enough motivation"_ Sure, I agree, just expanding on your point about 100k+ and bragging rights. :)

Comment: IMHO on 20k a privilege "Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower" seems to be very interesting.

Answer (score 6):

It's the nature of the beast. The people who started with the site are more likely to enjoy a higher reputation, as they contributed in the beta stages when voting was high, and these same posts continue to be seen by new people over the years and are voted up. They have contributed a lot to the site and also the years of experience on the site tends to reflect that they've also had years of programming experience, so are capable and give good answers.

The purpose of the site is to provide a good resource for programmers. So the 'classical' questions that stand the test of time will remain there and there's nothing newer members can do about that.

I'm glad those questions and answers are there, they've helped me and continue to help me in my journey as a programmer.

It depends on your purpose for being on the site. We all like rep (well mostly we do).  Does it matter if you never have the same rep as Jon Skeet and some other users?

With the advance in new technologies, we will never have a shortage of questions and skill sets needed to answer questions. Funnily enough, I'm studying in a fast developing field, mobile application development, and I find the diversity of what I'm learning means I can cast a broad net of subjects I've some knowledge of and little with any expertise (*yet*). So we can spin things in any positive or negative way.

I suggest head down tail up, focus on improving your programming skills and the rep will follow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution since there's no problem here. Imagine that everyone will "enjoy" faster reputation gain (including high-reputation users), how will this help? The ratio will remain the same, so even if you have more reputation, you'll still rank the same.

You should put efforts on helping whenever you can, regardless of the points - this will help you improve your skills and eventually will increase your reputation, you'll never know when you'll hit a good post that will attract many users.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not more difficult.

For example, I can compare Stack Overflow with [Stack Overflow in Russian](//ru.stackoverflow.com/). Stack Overflow has much more people; ruSO is young enough.

So on Stack Overflow you could get the answer quicklier, or as you said, find a ready answer with larger possibility.

Anyway, simple questions are still asked and sometimes answers for them get a large score. A larger community allows to get more score than you would on the smaller site.

For example, I'm sure I wouldn't get as much as +11 for [answer about skipped lines](//stackoverflow.com/a/35267985/4928642) on Stack Overflow in Russian.

Answer (score -15):

I think you are right, Jerry.

It might be a good idea to introduce some decay mechanism for the points you earn, that way not only the historical answers will become less important in future, but also the SO score would be more representative of the current activity of a member.

*"What distance does to size, time does to value"* - I think it was Plato.

Comment: any of the downvoters care to explain your actions? decay in points is succesfully used at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/UserRankingAndTierSystem), also in ranking authors in science (see [Hirsch index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index), so why exactly everyone considers it such a bad idea?

Comment: "*.. that way not only the historical answers will become less important*" - Why should they become less important? I think that good questions/answers should be rewarded the same, regardless of their date.

Comment: If somebody upvotes an old answer, that means it is still relevant and useful.

Comment: agree, Bill, but if the answer is constantly being upvoted, it will never decay to nothing

Comment: @coulminer if 1000 people upvote an answer, why do you think the answerer shouldn't get and keep that rep? 1000 people obviously found it helpful there, so why not? Why do you think content loses value over time? I think not.

Comment: There may not be a need for it to decay to nothing and posts are closed and deleted from the site daily, even posts with many upvotes, if they are deemed no longer useful/

Comment: @Magish I do not think that a recently (1 year, 10 years, 100 years ago - whatever) useful post needs to be closed. But what I do think, is that decay over time perfectly captures usefulness. Same way as discount rates are applied to determine the net present value of a cash flow. Its a common practice. Ok SO was founded later than win3.11 came out, but do you think that an author that answer a 1000 questions on win 3.11 should have the same rep *currently* as one who is actively collaborating with same amount on recent tech?

Comment: @coulminer yes, ofcourse they should. Rep is not some kind of currency, its a measure of how much the community trusts you. I think you fundamentally misunderstand the purpose of rep.

Comment: [What if reputation points have an expiration date?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299945/839601)

Comment: Of course its not a currency, but its a KPI. The greater your KPI the better you do. If you did well 9 years ago it doesn't mean that you do well now, but community still trusts you, according to the current point system. In scientific community, your Hirsch index decays over time if you don't "post", but your work remains for all to see and use, forever. Such a mechanism encourages authors to post on more recent questions, the successful and experienced users and the new bright helpers.

Comment: @coulminer What makes you think its a KPI? Its not.

Comment: @coulminer Dont worry, I think mostly "old" users downvoted your answer ;)

Comment: @JerrySwitalski I downvoted this, and I've been only here for 5 months.

Comment: thanks @Jerry :) For you, and anyone who is interested in the topic of user-rep, I just found a nice article, by [Movshovitz-Attias et al(2013)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ymovshov/Papers/asonam_2013.pdf), describing SO users and their points. Citations: a) it is possible to predict the reputation of a user from their behaviour in the first 3 months b) anomalously high-raking users mostly earn points by asking.